# .MDF / .SDF Database Client Software Requirement

Tags: database, vb.net, mdf, sdf, system-requirements

I have developed a program using VB.NET running with mysql (.mdf/.sdf) database file. It's definitely running well in my development machine.
Now I have compiled and come out the .exe file that want it to run in another personal computer without visual studio & other development tools. What are the software requirements for the PC to run the database file? Since i don't want to install visual studio, SQL management studio or other heavy development tool in the client PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you mean SQL Server Compact Edition rather than "mysql".

You either have to get the user to install the runtime on their desktop or package 7 dll files with your application, see: [How to Deploy a Sql Compact Database with an Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)